# Error in validating message of no votes PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

When there is no vote and all queries of the same print zero I want to display an error message saying no votes for this product.

The problem is that is not validating always shows me the message saying that there are no votes for this products when in fact if there are votes.

How can I correctly validate the error message when there are no votes of a product?

```
<?php
$id_product = "1";

    $stmtRating = $con->prepare("SELECT SUM(rating IN (4.5, 5))/COUNT(*)*100 AS pct_5_star,
       SUM(rating IN (3.5, 4))/COUNT(*)*100 AS pct_4_star,
       SUM(rating IN (2.5, 3))/COUNT(*)*100 AS pct_3_star,
       SUM(rating IN (1.5, 2))/COUNT(*)*100 AS pct_2_star,
       SUM(rating IN (0.5, 1))/COUNT(*)*100 AS pct_1_star,
       SUM(CASE WHEN rating IN (4.5, 5) THEN rating ELSE 0 END) AS in_5_star,
       SUM(CASE WHEN rating IN (3.5, 4) THEN rating ELSE 0 END) AS in_4_star,
       SUM(CASE WHEN rating IN (2.5, 3) THEN rating ELSE 0 END) AS in_3_star,
       SUM(CASE WHEN rating IN (1.5, 2) THEN rating ELSE 0 END) AS in_2_star,
       SUM(CASE WHEN rating IN (0.5, 1) THEN rating ELSE 0 END) AS in_1_star,
       AVG(rating) AS avg_rating,
       SUM(rating) as avg_total,
       COUNT(*) valuations
       FROM ratings
       WHERE id_product=?");


    $stmtRating->bind_param("i",$id_product);
    $stmtRating->execute();
    $stmtRating->bind_result(
        $pct_5_star,
        $pct_4_star,
        $pct_3_star,
        $pct_2_star,
        $pct_1_star,
        $in_5_star,
        $in_4_star,
        $in_3_star,
        $in_2_star,
        $in_1_star,
        $avg_rating,
        $avg_total,
        $valuations
    );

    //$stmtRating->fetch();
if ($stmtRating->num_rows>0) {
    while ($stmtRating->fetch()) {
      echo "$valuations <br>
      $pct_5_star <br>
      $pct_4_star <br>
      $pct_3_star <br>
      $pct_2_star <br>
      $pct_1_star <br>
      $in_5_star <br>
      $in_4_star <br>
      $in_3_star <br>
      $in_2_star <br>
      $in_1_star <br>
      $avg_rating <br>
      $avg_total <br>
      $valuations
";
    }
} else {
    echo "There are no votes for this product.";
}
```

Comment: @YourCommonSense Not all are deep in PDO, I prefer mysqli :)

Comment: BTW, with PDO your current problem doesn't exist. Keep preferring mysqli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use num_rows to validate anything. It's unreliable and useless.

in your case you could use result of fetch() to see whether your query returned anything.

```
if ($stmtRating->fetch()) {
    echo "$valuations <br>
      ...
    ";
    }
} else {
    echo "There are no votes for this product.";
}
```

Note that to keep your code size under control, you should use PDO instead of mysqli. The whole procedure will be 100 times shorter:

```
$id_product = "1";
$sql = "SELECT SUM(rating IN (4.5, 5))/COUNT(*)*100 AS pct_5_star ...";
$stmtRating = $con->prepare($sql);
$stmtRating->execute([$id_product]);
$rating = $stmtRating->fetch()
if ($rating) {
    foreach ($rating as $value) echo "$value<br>";
} else {
    echo "There are no votes for this product.";
}
```